# Error al crear función con tablas temporales

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Estoy en la creación de una función que contiene una tabla temporal, se me dificulta un poco el caso de usar la función con tabla temporal, desconozco totalmente si dentro de una función esta permitido ya que soy nuevo en el tema de funciones.

La función que estoy intentando crear es la siguiente:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionTest (
    @Anio   int=null,
    @Mes    int=Null,
    @Meses  int=6

)
RETURNS @Tabla TABLE (
    AnioMes INT,
    Viaje VARCHAR(30),
    IdPorte INT,
    Carga VARCHAR(20),
    Peso numeric(32, 16)
)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @AnioMes    varchar(8),
            @AnioMes6   varchar(8)

    if @Anio is null
        Select  @Anio   = YEAR(GETDATE()),
                @Mes    = MONTH(GETDATE())

    Select  @AnioMes    = (case when @Mes=12 then @Anio+1 else @Anio end *100 + Case when @Mes=12 then 1 else @Mes+1 end)*100 + 1
    Select  @AnioMes6   = convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(mm, -@Meses, @AnioMes), 112 )

    INSERT INTO @Tabla (AnioMes,Viaje,IdPorte,Carga,Peso)   
    SELECT  year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 + MONTH(cpsj.Delivery) as AnioMes,  
            tr.TId as Viaje,
            cpsj.PId as IdPorte,            
            CASE WHEN tr.Load = 1 THEN 'CARGADO'
                WHEN tr.Load = 2 THEN 'VACIO'
            END  as Carga, 
            cpsj.Weight as Peso,            
    into #Temp
    FROM BDNEW.dbo.CENPACKSTOREJOIN cpsj 
    inner join TRANS tr on cpsj.ipId = tr.ipId
    inner join OPERA oper on tr.OId = oper.OId  
    WHERE   cpsj.Id = 'ID001'
    AND     tr.Area = 'lost'
    AND     tr.Status       = 2
    GROUP BY cpsj.Delivery, cpsj.IName
    ORDER BY cpsj.ipId

    if @AnioMes6 < '20160101'
        insert #Temp
        SELECT  Year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 + MONTH(cpsj.Delivery) as AnioMes,  
                tr.TId as Viaje,
                cpsj.PId as IdPorte,        
                CASE WHEN tr.Load = 1 THEN 'CARGADO'
                    WHEN tr.Load = 2 THEN 'VACIO'
                END  as Carga, 
                cpsj.Weight as Peso,                
        FROM BDOLD.dbo.CENPACKSTOREJOIN cpsj 
        inner join TRANS tr on cpsj.ipId = tr.ipId
        inner join OPERA oper on tr.OId = oper.OId
        WHERE   cpsj.Id = 'ID001'
        AND     tr.Area = 'lost'    
        AND     tr.Status       = 2
        GROUP BY cpsj.Delivery, cpsj.IName 
        ORDER BY cpsj.ipId

    Delete  #Temp
    where   viaje in (
                    select MAX(Viaje)
                    from    #Temp
                    group by IdPorte
                    having COUNT(IdPorte) > 1
                    )

    
    Select  AnioMes,
            Viaje,
            IdPorte, 
            Carga, 
            Peso, 
    from #Temp
    GROUP BY AnioMes,IdPorte Viaje, Carga, Peso
    ORDER BY AnioMes,IdPorte

RETURN 

END
```

Si se fijan estoy haciendo uso de una tabla temporal llamada `#Temp`.

Como mensaje de error al intentar compilar la función obtengo como mensaje de error lo siguiente:

> Cannot access temporary tables from within a function.

Por eso mencionaba anteriormente si realmente se puede hacer uso de tablas temporales en una función.

Agradezco quien me pueda dar una orientación sobre como manejar esta función.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:**

Uno de los motivos principales por los cuales estoy haciendo uso de una función es que la requiero para usar en Power BI a través del método de conectividad de datos Direct Query. Inicialmente esta función era un procedimiento almacenado como lo muestro a continuación:

```
ALTER proc  [dbo].[sp_Test] 
@Anio   int=null,
@Mes    int=Null,
@Meses  int=6

as
begin
    set nocount on

    Declare @AnioMes    varchar(8),
            @AnioMes6   varchar(8)

    if @Anio is null
        Select  @Anio   = YEAR(GETDATE()),
                @Mes    = MONTH(GETDATE())

    Select  @AnioMes    = (case when @Mes=12 then @Anio+1 else @Anio end *100 + Case when @Mes=12 then 1 else @Mes+1 end)*100 + 1
    Select  @AnioMes6   = convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(mm, -@Meses, @AnioMes), 112 )
    
    SELECT  year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 + MONTH(cpsj.Delivery) as AnioMes,  
            tr.TId as Viaje,
            cpsj.PId as IdPorte,            
            CASE WHEN tr.Load = 1 THEN 'CARGADO'
                WHEN tr.Load = 2 THEN 'VACIO'
            END  as Carga, 
            cpsj.Weight as Peso,            
    into #Temp
    FROM BDNEW.dbo.CENPACKSTOREJOIN cpsj 
    inner join TRANS tr on cpsj.ipId = tr.ipId
    inner join OPERA oper on tr.OId = oper.OId  
    WHERE   cpsj.Id = 'ID001'
    AND     tr.Area = 'lost'
    AND     tr.Status       = 2
    GROUP BY cpsj.Delivery, cpsj.IName
    ORDER BY cpsj.ipId

    if @AnioMes6 < '20160101'
        insert #Temp
        SELECT  Year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 + MONTH(cpsj.Delivery) as AnioMes,  
                tr.TId as Viaje,
                cpsj.PId as IdPorte,        
                CASE WHEN tr.Load = 1 THEN 'CARGADO'
                    WHEN tr.Load = 2 THEN 'VACIO'
                END  as Carga, 
                cpsj.Weight as Peso,                
        FROM BDOLD.dbo.CENPACKSTOREJOIN cpsj 
        inner join TRANS tr on cpsj.ipId = tr.ipId
        inner join OPERA oper on tr.OId = oper.OId
        WHERE   cpsj.Id = 'ID001'
        AND     tr.Area = 'lost'    
        AND     tr.Status       = 2
        GROUP BY cpsj.Delivery, cpsj.IName 
        ORDER BY cpsj.ipId

    Delete  #Temp
    where   viaje in (
                    select MAX(Viaje)
                    from    #Temp
                    group by IdPorte
                    having COUNT(IdPorte) > 1
                    )

    
    Select  AnioMes,
            Viaje,
            IdPorte, 
            Carga, 
            Peso, 
    from #Temp
    GROUP BY AnioMes,IdPorte Viaje, Carga, Peso
    ORDER BY AnioMes,IdPorte


END
```

Ustedes se preguntaran porque cambio a una función y no hago uso del procedimiento almacenado desde Power BI, esto se debe a que no puedo hacer uso del procedimiento almacenado usando modo de conectividad de datos Direct Query.

Es así como he llegado a crear una función para solventar este problema que estoy presentando.

Comment: La [documentación de las funciones en sql server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#Restrictions), es clara: *User-defined functions cannot make use of dynamic SQL or temp tables. Table variables are allowed.* Tal vez quieras utilizar un [procedimiento almacenado](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/stored-procedures-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). Me parece más adecuado, basado en una lectura rápida de tu código

Comment: cual es el error??

Comment: @Arriel Anteriormente esta función hacia parte de un procedimiento almacenado pero ahora me veo en la obligación de trasladarlo a una función, ya que requiero hacer uso de una función desde Power BI lo cual me permitirá hacer el modo de conectividad de datos a través de Direct Query.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent El mensaje de error que obtengo es el siguiente `Cannot access temporary tables from within a function.`, según los comentarios que he leído no puedo hacer uso de tablas temporal en una función, aquí lo que quisiera saber debido a mi corto conocimiento es como puedo hacer uso de las tablas temporales en una función si realmente se puede o como puedo corregirla para que no me genere el error que menciono anteriormente

Comment: @JohnDoe Negativo no se puede ... estrictamente no se puede per por que una tabla temporal cuando puedes tener una tabla fija que usas como temporal ... no se si me entiendas  el concepto ... al principio la truncas y ejecutas la funcion y listo; al truncarla cada arranque te permite manejarla como un temporal ... incluso puedes truncarla al final para que quede limpia ... yo lo hago en algunos crons donde recibo datos de interface de un sistema unix y tengo que meter 2 a 3 millones de datos desde un LOAD FILE; y me permite tener indexadas las columnas... para el procesamiento en las funciones

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Ok, con tu comentario ya me queda mas que claro que no puedo hacer uso de las tablas temporales, ahora (y lo mas importante) como puedo hacer que mi función compile correctamente y no tengas errores ?

Comment: debugearla... la verdad que ese tema el profesional es @gbianchi, pero como te decimos en el chat ... tienes que plantear mejor tu duda y tu problema por que esto esta relacionado al consumo del recursos de base de datos por Power BI el cual cambia el contexto de cualquier respuesta ... que te vayan a dar....

Comment: Allí dice que puedes utilizar una variable tipo tabla, por que no lo intentas, lee la documentación de las variables tipo tabla, yo recuerdo haberlo cambiado a una variable tipo tabla o si no puedes hacer un subselect.

Comment: @DaveRincon Si te fijas en lo que he intentado de la función que estoy desarrollando allí utilizo una variable tipo tabla llamada `@Tabla`, hay algo mas que deba usar adicional a eso ?

Comment: Pues no veo tu variable de tipo tabla en la actualización pero tienes que generar la estructura de la tabla, ya que las variables tipo tabla no se crean solitas con el into #table, una vez que ya la tienes creada "Declarada" solo la cambias en todas tus consultas en lugar de #table usa '@table y el primer insert tiene que ser normal insert into '@table

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15   C. Declaring a variable of type table

Comment: @DaveRincon En la actualización solo se encuentra el código del procedimiento almacenado, lo que anteriormente era antes de convertirlo a una función.

Comment: en tu función tal cual como la tienes cambia tu #table por @table, claro primero la declaras y luego la usas y debería de funcionar, claro dependiendo tu versión de SQL creo que en el 2001 no hay variables de tipo tabla. Igual la función no puede regresar un select, tienes que hacer una funcion que regrese una tabla en tu return. y para imbocarla es select * from myfunciontabla()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He adaptado y he creado la función en base a los comentarios, en donde tengo por enterado que no se usan tablas temporales en funciones según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#Restrictions) y en donde he usado la variable tipo tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionTest (
    @Anio   int=null,
    @Mes    int=Null,
    @Meses  int=6

)
--Defino el OUTPUT de la función como una tabla en memoria
RETURNS @Tabla TABLE (
    AnioMes INT,
    Viaje VARCHAR(30),
    IdPorte INT,
    Carga VARCHAR(20),
    Peso numeric(32, 16)
)
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @AnioMes    varchar(8),
            @AnioMes6   varchar(8)

    if @Anio is null
        Select  @Anio   = YEAR(GETDATE()),
                @Mes    = MONTH(GETDATE())

    Select  @AnioMes    = (case when @Mes=12 then @Anio+1 else @Anio end *100 + Case when @Mes=12 then 1 else @Mes+1 end)*100 + 1
    Select  @AnioMes6   = convert(varchar(8), DATEADD(mm, -@Meses, @AnioMes), 112 )

    --Insertamos los datos en la tabla temporal
    INSERT INTO @Tabla (AnioMes,Viaje,IdPorte,Carga,Peso)   
    SELECT  year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 + MONTH(cpsj.Delivery) as AnioMes,  
            tr.TId as Viaje,
            cpsj.PId as IdPorte,            
            CASE WHEN tr.Load = 1 THEN 'CARGADO'
                WHEN tr.Load = 2 THEN 'VACIO'
            END  as Carga, 
            cpsj.Weight as Peso,            
    FROM BDNEW.dbo.CENPACKSTOREJOIN cpsj 
    inner join TRANS tr on cpsj.ipId = tr.ipId
    inner join OPERA oper on tr.OId = oper.OId  
    WHERE   cpsj.Id = 'ID001'
    AND     tr.Area = 'lost'
    AND     tr.Status       = 2
    GROUP BY cpsj.Delivery, cpsj.IName
    ORDER BY cpsj.ipId

    if @AnioMes6 < '20160101'
        insert @Tabla
        SELECT  Year(cpsj.Delivery)*100 + MONTH(cpsj.Delivery) as AnioMes,  
                tr.TId as Viaje,
                cpsj.PId as IdPorte,        
                CASE WHEN tr.Load = 1 THEN 'CARGADO'
                    WHEN tr.Load = 2 THEN 'VACIO'
                END  as Carga, 
                cpsj.Weight as Peso,                
        FROM BDOLD.dbo.CENPACKSTOREJOIN cpsj 
        inner join TRANS tr on cpsj.ipId = tr.ipId
        inner join OPERA oper on tr.OId = oper.OId
        WHERE   cpsj.Id = 'ID001'
        AND     tr.Area = 'lost'    
        AND     tr.Status       = 2
        GROUP BY cpsj.Delivery, cpsj.IName 
        ORDER BY cpsj.ipId

    Delete  @Tabla
    where   viaje in (
                    select MAX(Viaje)
                    from    @Tabla
                    group by IdPorte
                    having COUNT(IdPorte) > 1
                    )


RETURN 

END
```

En resumidas cuentas he tenido algunos puntos en cuenta que me han compartido y quiero compartir a quien se presente con un problema de este tipo

1. Es necesario definir el output de la función como una tabla en memoria.
2. Posteriormente se insertan los datos en dicha tabla.
3. En mi función puedo hacer los `INSERT` que desee.
4. No requiero hacer un `SELECT` al final como lo haría en el procedimiento almacenado que les compartí en la actualización, si previamente lo había llenado en `@Tabla` este va a ser el retorno de la función.
5. En vez de usar #Temp usa la tabla de retorno que se creado `@Tabla`, ya que se trata de una tabla mas dentro de la función.

Espero que ha alguien mas le sea de gran utilidad mi respuesta.

Comment: Esto era lo que te decía muy buena respuesta.